# concentate 2 vectors to string by common element

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with 2 columns. If an element appears in both columns this should be the grouping criteria. I then want to create a new column which concentates all elements by group into a single, sorted string.

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~col1, ~col2,
  "a", "b",
  "b","c",
  "c","b",
  "d",NA,
  "e","d",
  "f","d",
  "g","d",
  "h","i",
  "i","h",
  "j", NA
)

outcome <- tibble::tribble(
  ~result,
  c("a_b_c"),
  c("d_e_f_g"),
  c("h_i"),
  c("j")
)
```

any help is appreciated since I have not yet found a starting point to solve the question thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the connected components from igraph and paste.

```
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)

df %>% 
  mutate(col2 = coalesce(col2, col1)) %>%
  as.matrix %>%
  graph_from_edgelist %>%
  components %>%
  groups %>%
  sapply(paste, collapse = "_") %>%
  stack
```

giving:

```
   values ind
1   a_b_c   1
2 d_e_f_g   2
3     h_i   3
4       j   4
```